# How to read the source content-type from each Eclipse file?

Tags: eclipse, character-encoding, iconv

I have an Eclipse project that contains several source files, with a bunch of different encodings: some files are `UTF8`, some others are `ISO-8859-1`, others more are `windows-1252`.

Moreover, there are files whose encoding is explicit (it can bee seen in each file *Properties* window) while that of others is *Inherited from container*.

I need to convert them to UTF8 - and I've already found I can use iconv for that - see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25939399/3127111) for details -, but since they're more than one thousand, I can't convert them one by one: is there any programmatic way to get the encoding from the IDE or something similar?

I'm on Windows, I may do some shell scripting and / or write auxiliary software.

Comment: An Eclipse plugin can get the encoding easily, anything else is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The charset setting of project file could be found in `${PROJECT_FOLDER}/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs`
Since there are so many files in your project. Create a simple Eclipse plugin could reduce the effort. Here are the steps:

1. Select Eclipse menu item *New > Project... > Plug-in Project*
2. Accept default values and goto [last page](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Fintro%2Fpde_overview.htm), choose `Hello, World` template.
3. Open and edit plugin.xml, adding required plugin **org.eclipse.core.resources** in **Dependencies** page.
4. Edit `SampleAction.java`, refer the sample code below..
5. Create a **Debug Configuration** for execute Eclipse Application.
6. Start the eclipse and import your project.
7. Select menu item *Sample Menu* to invoke `public void run(IAction action)`.

Sample code of Eclipse resource API:

```
//import org.eclipse.core.resources.*;
//import org.eclipse.core.runtime.*;
public void run(IAction action) {
    final boolean keepHistory = true;
    IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("yourProjectName");
    project.accept(new IResourceVisitor() {
        public boolean visit(IResource resource) {
            IFile file = (IFile)resource;
            try {
                String charset = file.getCharset(true);
                if (!"UTF-8".equals(charset)) {
                    InputStream is = file.getContents();
                    //convert to UTF-8 and save it
                    String str = new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(is), charset);
                    file.setContents(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8")), true, keepHistory, null);
                    //remove charset setting
                    file.setCharset("UTF-8", null);
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                //log error... maybe process later via project.getFile(new Path(projectRelativePath))
                Activator.getDefault().getLog().log(new Status(IStatus.INFO, Activator.PLUGIN_ID, 
                        file.getProjectRelativePath().toString(), e));
            }
            return false;
        }
    }, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, IResource.FILE);
}
```